# What is the Manual of the Modrossus?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds

Recently, when trying to find bits of lore for characters in a game I'm running set in the Nerian Nexus, former home to Master Mage Adrian Eldrich, I ran into a mention of a "Manual of the Modrossus" in the *Power Profiles* book. At the time, I didn't find an immediate explanation, and so instead went with the "Medallion of the Modrossus", which did have defined status in the *Gadget Guides* book and in one of the later *Netherwar* adventures. Now, I'm kind of curious. Is there any definition of this Manual? Is it just meant to be a reference to the "Magic of the Modrossus" mentioned in the *Power Profiles*?

> The legendary Manual and Medallion of the Modrossus are entrusted to Earth’s Master Mage.

FWIW, the Medallion of the Modrossus from *Gadget Guides*:

> ### MEDALLION OF THE MODROSSUS
>
> This silver clasp bearing the Mark of the Modrossus (a circle
> within a triangle) is part of the regalia of Earth’s Master
> Mage. The Medallion is a powerful talisman of light and
> truth against the forces of darkness and chaos. When
> willed, it emits a pure blue-white light able to blind, read
> thoughts, or banish creatures of supernatural evil. Its power
> is limited, however, by the arcane knowledge and skill of
> its wielder, who must possess the Magic power (that is, an
> array of Alternate Effects with a magic descriptor). See the
> sample Magic power in Chapter 6 of the Hero’s Handbook.
>
> *Medallion of the Modrossus: three Dynamic Alternate
> Effects: Ranged Affliction (blinding light; Impaired,
> Disabled, Unaware), Cumulative, Limited to Vision;
> Mind Reading; Nullify Summon Supernatural Creatures,
> Perception Range), Removable (–1 point) • 5 points*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Mutants and Masterminds Monday, Steve started explaining it was a "powerful mystical artifact", but then Crystal interjected that it was explained in the 2e *Book of Magic*

> ### Manual of the Modrossus
>
> This legendary tome of arcane lore is the most powerful collection of
> spells and rituals for good ever known. Its origins are shrouded in antiquity, but it has passed through the hands of most (if not all) of Earth’s
> Master Mages over the millennia.
>
> The Manual is a heavy book of ancient vellum pages covered with illuminated script in a variety of languages, many of them completely unknown
> to modern scholars. It is bound in deep blue leather, said to be dragon-hide,
> with brass cover-caps, a locking clasp, and the sign of the Modrossus—a circle inside a triangle—on the cover in brass. In spite of its apparent age, the
> Manual is actually far older and virtually indestructible by mortal means.
>
> Among its unusual properties is the fact that the last page of the book is
> always blank; there always appears to be space to write new text, and many
> Master Mages have added to the Manual over the years.
>
> The Manual was lost for a time in the late 19th and early 20th centuries, claimed by the Cult of Kar’Kradas after the untimely death of
> Master Mage Violet Pennyworth. Adrian Eldrich later reclaimed it from
> the Cult’s vile clutches, and it now resides in a warded vault in his sanctum in Freedom City.